# Failed to run tensorflow distributed MNIST test

Tags: tensorflow, distributed, deep-learning

I installed tensorflow 0.8 by building from source.
I use AWS EC2 g2.8xlarge instance which has 4 GPUs.
I tried to run tensorflow distributed mnist test, code in here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dist_test/scripts/dist_mnist_test.sh

my script:

```
bash dist_mnist_test.sh "grpc://localhost:2223 grpc://localhost:2224"
```

and I got this message:

```
E0609 14:53:07.430440599   62872 tcp_client_posix.c:173]     failed to connect to 'ipv4:127.0.0.1:2223': socket error: connection refused
E0609 14:53:07.445297934   62873 tcp_client_posix.c:173]     failed to connect to 'ipv4:127.0.0.1:2224': socket error: connection refused
```

Any one know what is wrong here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script does not run standalone. In particular, it expects that you have created a TensorFlow cluster with workers running at each of the addresses *before* running the script. The [`create_tf_cluster.sh`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dist_test/scripts/create_tf_cluster.sh) script can set up such a cluster using Kubernetes. The [`dist_test.sh`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ff75787c166e4f43560f5f55388ab9bfbe73eeb0/tensorflow/tools/dist_test/scripts/dist_test.sh) script runs these scripts end-to-end.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37823338/3574081) to your other question, which has a suggested script for running MNIST on distributed TensorFlow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's a networking problem here. The first debugging step I would take is to ensure that the sockets 2223 and 2224 are actually being listened to using a tool like netstat. Here's a good general description of how to do that:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/278448/how-to-know-what-program-is-listening-on-a-given-port

If that works, then try using telnet to connect to the socket manually, to make sure the network addressing is working correctly.