# Questions regarding tensorflow distributed training example

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am studying distributed tensorflow example: [tensorflow distributed training code template](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/distributed/index.html#putting-it-all-together-example-trainer-program)
It's a **between-graph** replicas and **asynchronous** training example template.

I also found the following code example which follows the same fashion (**between-graph, asynchronous**).This example is from [murry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37823338/6437725). I pasted it below to help me express my questions:

1, In this example, say I have two worker tasks and two ps tasks, do all the Variables: `hid_w,hid_b,sm_w,sm_b...` are placed on parameter server(ps) devices? If yes, does the placement follow a round-robin fashion (`hid_w` to `ps/task:0`, `hid_b` to `ps/task:1`, `sm_w` to `ps/task:0`, `sm_b` to `ps/task:1` .... )

2, If I want to achieve **synchronous replicated training**, I can use `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` as a wrapper. However, `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` can only wrap gradient descent based `Optimizer` such as `tf.train.AdagradOptimizer` and `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`. My question is **how to achieve synchronous training of algorithm like K-means that does not use any `Optimizer`?**; is there any way that can achieve synchronous training without `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer`

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

# Flags for defining the tf.train.ClusterSpec
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("ps_hosts", "",
                           "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("worker_hosts", "",
                           "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")

# Flags for defining the tf.train.Server
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("job_name", "", "One of 'ps', 'worker'")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("task_index", 0, "Index of task within the job")

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS


def main(_):
  ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
  worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")

  # Create a cluster from the parameter server and worker hosts.
  cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})

  # Create and start a server for the local task.
  server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
                           job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                           task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

  if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()
  elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":

    # Assigns ops to the local worker by default.
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
        worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
        cluster=cluster)):



      # Variables of the hidden layer
      hid_w = tf.Variable(
          tf.truncated_normal([IMAGE_PIXELS * IMAGE_PIXELS, FLAGS.hidden_units],
                              stddev=1.0 / IMAGE_PIXELS), name="hid_w")
      hid_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([FLAGS.hidden_units]), name="hid_b")

      # Variables of the softmax layer
      sm_w = tf.Variable(
          tf.truncated_normal([FLAGS.hidden_units, 10],
                              stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(FLAGS.hidden_units)),
          name="sm_w")
      sm_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name="sm_b")

      x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, IMAGE_PIXELS * IMAGE_PIXELS])
      y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

      hid_lin = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(x, hid_w, hid_b)
      hid = tf.nn.relu(hid_lin)

      y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.nn.xw_plus_b(hid, sm_w, sm_b))
      loss = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(y, 1e-10, 1.0)))

      global_step = tf.Variable(0)

      train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01).minimize(
          loss, global_step=global_step)

      saver = tf.train.Saver()
      summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
      init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    # Create a "supervisor", which oversees the training process.
    sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                             logdir="/tmp/train_logs",
                             init_op=init_op,
                             summary_op=summary_op,
                             saver=saver,
                             global_step=global_step,
                             save_model_secs=600)

    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)

    # The supervisor takes care of session initialization, restoring from
    # a checkpoint, and closing when done or an error occurs.
    with sv.managed_session(server.target) as sess:
      # Loop until the supervisor shuts down or 1000000 steps have completed.
      step = 0
      while not sv.should_stop() and step < 1000000:
        # Run a training step asynchronously.
        # See `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` for additional details on how to
        # perform *synchronous* training.

        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
        train_feed = {x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys}

        _, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step], feed_dict=train_feed)

    # Ask for all the services to stop.
    sv.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```